# What kind of 3 pin fan connector is this, and where can I buy one?

Tags: fan, connector

I have a Cyberpower UPS with a very noisy 80mm fan, so I want to replace the fan with a quieter one.  I bought a well-reviewed fan from Noctua, but the 3 pin connector doesn't quite fit.  I didn't realize there were two standards for 3 pin fan connectors.  So what is this connector called, and where can I buy an adapter or a fan that uses it?

The original fan from Cyberpower is labeled PSAD18025BH, and spec sheet is here:
http://www.nstech.wtools.com.tw/PDF/ns26_PS8025.pdf

The connector with the yellow glue is from Cyberpower, the other one is Noctua.

EDIT: I realized the two connectors don't have the same pinout.  Standard order is gnd, +12v, tachometer.
This connector order is gnd, RD signal, +12v.
Before I physically mod anything, I'd like to know what happens if I swap the RD and hot wires, shave off the plastic, and plug this in.  Apparently RD signals when the motor is locked, but a tach should do a similar thing by reporting 0rpm...?

[image: top view]

[image: side view]

Comment: There are in fact many types of 3-pin connectors.  The "standard" used on mainboards is from the Molex KK 254 or KK 100 family, or any of the clones.  The advantage of this family is a larger housing with relatively low insertion and removal force, making it finger friendly.  The "standard" used in power supplies and graphics cards and other "internal" components is usually from the JST XH family.  The advantage of this family is the compact housing, stiffer pins and tighter lock.  This is why the modded KK doesn't fit securely on the XH.  They are both commonly used inside a computer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's a JST XH 2.5mm connector.  Digikey 455-2219-ND, pins are Digikey 455-1135-1-ND.  You can crimp it with an Engineer PA-09 hand crimper.  I just had to solve the same issue replacing a power supply fan.

Comment: Wow thank you!  I ended up filing down the connector instead.  It still doesn't fit very snugly, so I hot glued it in place.  If it ever falls out, I'll know where to buy the real thing!

Answer (score 2):

It might make sense to simply, very carefully disengage the pins with a needle, then swap the wires to use the existing connectors, or to cut and solder together wires as needed with some heatshrink over it.

From memory, I've seen a similar connector in a fan inside a power supply, and it had *significantly thicker cables*  and the fan that you have linked the datasheet for has a higher input power rating than a random noctua fan I looked up. *This worries me*.

I can't find any literature on the potential risks of running a fan on slightly higher than recommended current, but if you're doing this I would keep an eye on the cables connecting the fan to the system to make sure they don't overheat, and you may experience slightly shorter lifespan due to this.  It may be nothing, and no one's mentioned replacing PSU fans with a regular fan being dangerous [in this question](https://superuser.com/questions/9050/could-i-replace-a-stock-psu-fan-with-a-more-quiet-one).

Comment: Thanks. I just updated the question when I realized the pin orders are different. The wires on these two fans are the same thickness. With AC power (which I'm more familiar with), a device will only draw as much current as it needs, regardless of how much excess current is available on the circuit breaker. Not sure if that applies here.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if the wires match (+, - and sense) I would just use some sand paper or sharp knife to adapt the connector for it.